# Cannot start/stop cache within lock or transaction

Tags: locking, ignite

I have create a IgniteCache namely *MYIGNITECACHE1* with  as  in Single Thread and locked one row Entry in it. 
And in same Locking period and Similar Thread I am creating another IgniteCache namely *MYIGNITECACHE2* with  as .

But while creating second Cache with  as , I am getting IgniteException as Cannot start/stop cache within lock or transaction.

I am creating Cache as,

*Ignite.getOrCreateCache("MYIGNITECACHE2");*

Comment: I need a solution so that I can Avoid this Exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is correct behavior. To avoid this you can either create a separate thread and create the cache there, or created all required caches before acquiring the lock.